# Facebook browser CORS issue

Tags: facebook, cross-domain, cross-origin-read-blocking

Trying to figure out an issue that popped up in Sentry today.

I've never seen the 'Facebook' browser come up before, but here it is, all seem to be ios devices:

[image]

I don't really understand how there could be an origin issue here as the url listed has the same root domain. Has anyone run into this before? [image]

Comment: The error message does not mention, _what_ it tries to access; it simply says your page was the origin of the access attempt, but it does not mention what the actual “target” was. I’m guessing this is probably related to some social plugin embedded into the page.

Comment: do you have any iframe on this page ?

Comment: No iframe on the page, it's a normal sign up page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means someone is opening your url within the facebook app. Facebook app has its own browser shell to open the link within the app.

You will be able to replicate this issue if you open it from within the facebook app.

Comment: I am indeed able to trigger the same issue in Sentry when I installed the facebook app and used that browser, thank you.

Comment: Facebook browser is by far one of the worst browser implementations there is. They use the device native browser, but don't implement many things on top like service worker, pop ups and CORS is not implemented properly as you can see.